# Eclipse PDT JavaScript support includes only ECMAScript 3

Tags: javascript, eclipse-pdt

I have Eclipse (PDT) 2020-03 (4.15.0) installed with JSDT too.

I have an existing PHP project with JavaScript support enabled, but included ECMAScript libraries are stuck on version 3 (1999!!).

How can I change ECMAScript included version? Thank you!

Comment: Try the wild web developer plugin from the marketplace.https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/wild-web-developer-html-css-javascript-typescript-nodejs-angular-json-yaml-kubernetes-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upcoming Eclipse 2020-06 replaces old JSDT with WildWebDeveloper. This version fully support latest ECMA.